# How to start LED wirelessly in a very compact and cheap module?

Tags: led, wireless, low-power

I have been thinking and researching about this issue for a while with no success. I am hoping someone can solve this problem in the community.

I want to have many small modules each with a small battery and LED, not connected to anything else.

I need to be able to arbitrary turn an LED on (no need to turn them off). For example I want to send a command to LED no 10 and turn that specific LED on.

Imagine a number of wireless relays, but with the constraints that each system has to be very low power and very compact (and ofcourse very cheap).

Comment: IR receiver module and a small MCU.

Comment: Or a cheap MCU with an RF receiver or transceiver, e.g. http://www.digikey.com.au/product-detail/en/PIC12LF1840-I%2FP/PIC12LF1840-I%2FP-ND/2651360

Comment: Xbee modules can do direct IO mapping, make a master with about 8-10 IO's transmit to others in the network, and mirror the outputs to also turn on their IO's to match the master.

Comment: Sounds like a TI CC2450 with Bluetooth LE (or Bluetooth Smart for the politically correct) could do that job nicely.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like a [Wixel](http://www.pololu.com/product/1336).  It combines a low-power MCU with a radio.  It may be possible to combine a low-cost MCU with a low-cost radio (for instance, an nRF24L01) to achieve a slightly lower cost per unit, but the development time would be higher.

There are also Bluetooth LE modules like the BlueGiga BLE112 that may work well.  The last time I looked at it, the BLE112 seemed a little harder to program than the Wixel (more complicated development tools), but the cost per unit is lower.

Comment: Thanks, don't have enough rep to vote up hoping someone else will.

$20 is a bit high for my usecase but could work in proto phase. Do you have an idea how long would a Wixel stay awake before requiring an new battery (assuming AA battery)

Comment: They consume 30mA max and ~100uA in sleep mode.  Assuming a constant 30mA load on a battery with 2000mAh capacity (two AA batteries in series to get the required 3V), that would be about 67 hours.  If the Wixel can be put to sleep most of the time and just wake up periodically to check for a radio command, you could extend the battery life quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like the Moteino from LowPowerLabs might work.

[https://lowpowerlab.com/shop/index.php?*route*=Moteino/moteino-r4](https://lowpowerlab.com/shop/index.php?_route_=Moteino/moteino-r4)